# Visual basic 2010 removing from listbox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Well i got some hard time figuring out what am I doing wrong.
Basically I need to remove Listbox1 items that are less then avarage, but its giving me:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=InvalidArgument=Value of '9' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

```
Private Sub Label3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click
    Dim Myrand As New Random
    Dim res As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim tot As Double
    Dim avarage As Double

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    For i = 0 To 14 Step 1
        res = Math.Round(Myrand.NextDouble, 3)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(res)
        tot = tot + res
    Next

    avarage = tot / ListBox1.Items.Count
    MsgBox(avarage)

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step 1
        If ListBox1.Items(i) < avarage Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox("Removed " & n & " items!")
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is grabbing the max Count at the start of the For/Next Loop and [doesn't reevaluate it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VB.FOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true). Try iterating backwards that way you are removing from where you have been not from where you are going.

i.e.

```
For i = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Items(i) < avarage Then
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next
```

From above MSDN Link emphasis mine:

> When a For...Next loop starts, Visual Basic evaluates start, end, and
>   step. This is the **only** time it evaluates these values. It then assigns
>   start to counter. Before it runs the statement block, it compares
>   counter to end. If counter is already larger than the end value (or
>   smaller if step is negative), the For loop ends and control passes to
>   the statement following the Next statement. Otherwise the statement
>   block runs.

Comment: Yep this was the catch... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an item, it's no longer in the list, so the list gets shorter, and your original count is no longer valid. Just decrement `i`:

```
Private Sub Label3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click
    Dim Myrand As New Random
    Dim res As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim tot As Double
    Dim avarage As Double

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    For i = 0 To 14
        res = Math.Round(Myrand.NextDouble, 3)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(res)
        tot += res
    Next

    avarage = tot / ListBox1.Items.Count
    MsgBox(avarage)

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBox1.Items(i) < avarage Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            i -= 1
            n += 1
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox("Removed " & n & " items!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Even by decrementing i I am having the same error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=InvalidArgument=Value of '7' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Thank you for helping and simplifying my code! It works now when I changed that For Next loop